# Stored Procedures work fine in MSQL Studio, but now in PHP

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sqlsrv

SQL Stored Procedure returns NULL when I call it from my mobile app or a web browser, but the same procedure returns what it has to when called using SQLPro for MSSQL software

```
    if( $conn == FALSE ) {
        echo "Connection failed.";
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }


    $query = "EXEC dbo.sp_Pok_Details @oe=17,@code='5907769000409'";

    $getProducts = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);  


    if ($getProducts == FALSE) 
    {
        die(FormatErrors(sqlsrv_errors()));  
    } 


    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($getProducts, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))  
    {  
        $returnArray[] = $row;
    }  

    echo json_encode($returnArray);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Explanations:**

You need to put `SET NOCOUNT ON` as first line in your stored procedure to prevent returning the number of rows affected by the T-SQL statements as part of the result set. This is the reason for your NULL results.

If you can't change your stored procedure, use `sqlsrv_next_result()` to make the next result active and then fetch the data.

As a note, always use prepared statements and parameterized queries to prevent SQL injection. With PHP Driver for SQL Server, function `sqlsrv_query()` does both statement preparation and statement execution and can be used to execute parameterized queries.

**Example (based on your code)**:

```
<?php

    if( $conn === false ) {
        echo "Connection failed.";
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }

    $query = "EXEC dbo.sp_Pok_Details @oe = ?, @code = ?";
    $params = array(17, '5907769000409');
    $getProducts = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query, $params);  
    if ($getProducts === false) {
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));  
    } 

    // Just for test - make additional call(s) to get the count of the active result sets
    do {
       while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($getProducts, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {  
          echo 'Current rowset'.'<br>';
       }  
    } while (sqlsrv_next_result($getProducts));
    // Or if you have only one result set
    //while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($getProducts, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {  
    //  $returnArray[] = $row;
    //}

    echo json_encode($returnArray);
?>
```

Comment: Hey Zhorov, thanks for your answer, but I still get null result from json_encode

Comment: @JohnAron I've updated the answer, but in most cases using `SET NOCOUNT ON` solves this issue. Please, check the count of the result sets. Thanks.