# No rows returned when trying to run SQL Serverstored procedure in PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

I'm trying to run a SQL Server stored procedure from PHP, but no matter what I try no rows are returned. Here is what I use to execute the SP inside Azure Data Studio, as a test:

```
DECLARE @RC int
DECLARE @StartPortName varchar(30)
DECLARE @EndPortName varchar(30)

EXECUTE @RC = [dbo].[uspGetWaypoints] 
   'Chicago', 'Thunder Bay'
GO
```

The above correctly returns 3 rows in Azure Data Studio. In my PHP, however, I can't get these results to show. Here is my code. All that is printed is "Successfully connected!!!" and "There are no rows".

```
$serverName = "tcp:example.windows.net,1433";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"Example", "UID"=>"admin", "PWD"=>"password");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo );

if ( $conn === false ) {
  echo "Could not connect.\n";
  die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
} else {
  echo "Successfully connected!!!<br/>";
}

$outputWaypoints = '';
$startPort = 'Chicago';
$endPort = 'Thunder Bay';
$callWaypoints = "{CALL uspGetWaypoints (?,?) }";
$paramsWaypoints = [ 
                [$startPort, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN],
                [$endPort, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN],
                [&$outputWaypoints, SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT],
            ];
$resultWaypoints = sqlsrv_query($conn, $callWaypoints, $paramsWaypoints);


if ($err = sqlsrv_errors()) {
  echo "There were errors or warnings!<br/>";
  print_r($err);
  echo "<br/>";
}

if ($resultWaypoints && sqlsrv_has_rows($resultWaypoints)) {
  echo "There are rows<br/>";
} else {
  echo "There are no rows<br/>";
}

while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($resultWaypoints, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC)) {
  print_r($row[0] . ' ' . $row[1]);
  echo "<br/>";
}
```

Comment: Does the SP return rows when called with identical parameters in SSMS?

Comment: I don't have SSMS, I'm on a Mac. But when I run it in Azure Data Studio with the same parameters ('Chicago' and 'Thunder Bay') it returns rows as expected. That's why I figure there's just something slightly off with my PHP

Comment: @Bryce This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58788361/stored-procedures-work-fine-in-msql-studio-but-now-in-php/58796973#58796973) may help. Try to place `SET NOCOUNT ON` as first line in your stored procedure, or if you can't change this procedure, fetch all result sets.